# How to render my multidimensional array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render my array of objects inside my table but it shows "Cannot read property 'monthlytarget' of undefined", I am using axios to fetch the result and render inside the table

Axios :

```
   http.get(apiReportsEndpoint+"?empid="+this.props.match.params.id) 
        .then(response =>{  
            this.setState({
                report:response.data.data.monthlytarget
            })            
        });
```

Response I receive from API

```
   "data":{
      "monthlytarget":[
         {
            "quarter":1,
            "period_start":"2019-04-01",
            "monthlytarget":{
               "04":{
                  "targetpm":"213120",
                  "invoice_values":[

                  ],
                  "revenuepm":0,
                  "targetpercentage":0,
                  "joinees":0
               },
               "05":{
                  "targetpm":"213120",
                  "invoice_values":[

                  ],
                  "revenuepm":0,
                  "targetpercentage":0,
                  "joinees":0
               }
            } 
         },
         { quarter":2 ...},
         { quarter":3 ...},
      ] 
      
   }
```

I want to render values inside "monthlytarget" as rows inside table

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>MONTH</th>
        <th>TARGET PER MONTH</th>
        <th>REVENUE PER MONTH</th> 
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

      {
      this.state.report.map((revenuereport) =>{ 
         {Object.keys.map.monthlytarget(premise,index) => (
                <tr>
                   <td>{index}</td>
                   <td>{premise.targetpm}</td>
                   <td>{premise.revenuepm}</td>
                 </tr>
          ))}                                                   
      })
  }      
 </tbody>
```

Comment: So there is one table that has all rows `data.monthyTarget[x].monthlyTarget[y]`? Or each data.monthyTarget needs it's own table?

Comment: every month has monthlytarget, month name marked by key 0,1,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create one table out of all the data you could do the following:

```
this.state.report
  .map(({ monthlytarget }) => Object.entries(monthlytarget))
  .flat()
  .map(([key,value], index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{index}</td>
      <td>{value.targetpm}</td>
      <td>{value.revenuepm}</td>
    </tr>
  ));
```

Comment: Thanks @HMR but Using flat() didnt help to display month numbers

Comment: @VinodKumar Updated the answer, you are not using the month numbers in your question but in my answer the month number is available as `key`.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that

Answer (score 1):

It should be...

```js
this.state.report.map(({ monthlytarget }, i) =>
    Object.values(monthlytarget).map({ targetpm, revenuepm }, i) => 
    <tr>
        <td>{i}</td>
        <td>{targetpm}</td>
        <td>{revenuepm}</td>
    </tr>
))
```

Comment: Nope, that should be Object.values and maybe flatten the array before making the jsx

Comment: Thank you :). I was in a frenzy to get this answer in, lol.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by calling `Object.keys.map.monthlytarget`? if you are trying to loop the array and get JSX, do this:

```js
this.state.report.map((revenuereport) =>
  Object.keys(revenuereport.monthlytarget).map((premise, index) => (
    <tr>
      <td>{index}</td>
      <td>{revenuereport.monthlytarget[premise].targetpm}</td>
      <td>{revenuereport.monthlytarget[premise].revenuepm}</td>
    </tr>
  ))
);
```

Do pay attention to indents and brackets, code snippet in the question seems not gonna work at all.

Comment: If you use Object.values you can replace `revenuereport.monthlytarget[premise].` with `premise.`. You're still stuck with a multi dimensional array so maybe flatten that before generating jsx

Comment: @HMR not gonna make too much modification to his original code, I just fix the syntax error.

Comment: @ObooCheng It helped me to exactly get what I wanted